# Git does not recognize my global user.email inside RStudio

Tags: r, github, rstudio, git-commit

I am trying to commit my script changes inside RStudio, but I always get an error about not having a git account to refer to.

I have already tried to run in RStudio's Terminal:

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Then I confirm that my account is correctly recognized:

```
$ git config --global --list
user.email=my@email.com
```

I also refreshed the Git tab, and reopened the commit window, to no avail.

I checked `Tools --> Version Control --> Project Setup...`, which show my project URL correctly.

I expected to be solved after my e-mail being shown by the Terminal, but that's not the case.

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: Try to restart RStudio. Or go to `Settings -> Version Control -> GitHub`. You can add Github account for you current project there.

Comment: @iago I am using a Docker image of RStudio (Rocker/verse) on a Linux server

Comment: @DinkoPehar If you mean ```Tools --> Version Control --> Project Setup...``` it is also setup correctly.

Comment: @Hart I ment `File - Settings - Version Control - Github`

Comment: @DinkoPehar I've searched ```File - Settings``` both in Linux and Windows, and I am not able to see that option. The only similar would be ```Tools - Global Options...```

Comment: @HartRadev Shortcut is `Ctrl + Alt + S `.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201532/discussion-between-hart-radev-and-dinko-pehar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the solution was to sign in with my user.name instead of my user.email:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Indeed, I already put that line in my question, but I had only tried the user.email one (I thought they would be interchangeable).